# creating a data studio plugin - how do I use oauth2 "client Credentials"

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am trying to create a Data Studio plugin using oauth2 - however the documentation is not clear.

It says we should create the function getOAuthService() it doesn't say how you get the users own Client ID and Secret they entered in earlier when they created the screens nor what to do if don't need to use all the suggested fields for Oauth2.

Eg I was able to get the token using Postman with the following creds:

[image: PostMan for Search Metrics]

When I try to use Client credentials- then I get an error message saying

> Script error message: Authorization base URL is required.
>    Script error cause: USER
>    Script error stacktrace: 
>     :45
>     validate_:42
>     :312
>     get3PAuthorizationUrls:143

Obviously this isn't going to be possible to supply a base auth url - as its not requred by `client_credential` oauth2 flows.  How can I get this working?

Here is the code I am using:

```
     function getOAuthService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('searchMetrics')
  .setTokenUrl('http://api.searchmetrics.com/v3/token')
  .setGrantType('client_credentials')
    .setClientId('****removed****')
    .setClientSecret('*****removed*****')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
};

function get3PAuthorizationUrls() {
  return getOAuthService().getAuthorizationUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the [Authentication and Authorization guide](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth#oauth2) from Data Studio developer site for implementing OAuth2.

A few important notes:

- The OAuth2 library [setup guide](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#1-create-the-oauth2-service) will provide you with detailed information about `OAuth2.createService`. Since the documentation is available at the library's site, it was repeated in Data Studio developer site.
- The process for getting the client Id and secret depends on which provider you are connecting to. Each service provides has their own process for this.
- You can(*and should*) pass the authorization base url while using `OAuth2.createService`. Example [here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth#add_and_setup_oauth2_for_apps_script_library) and also [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#1-create-the-oauth2-service).
- If you want to see example implementation for OAuth2 authentication, you can have a look at the example codes in our open source repo: [Github connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/github/main.js#L818), [Meetup connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/meetup/src/oauth.js), [Spotify connector](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/spotify/src/connector.js#L24).
- Finally, after the OAuth2 process is complete, you can get the token by using `.getAccessToken()`. See the examples above for implementation details.

Edit: *For future viewers:* If you are using `client_credentials` and passing off a service account, you can use `authType: "NONE"` and use the OAuth2 library to generate the token.

Comment: Thanks @Minhaz - appreciate the help.  I had a look through the examples and unfortunately they don't support a Grant type of "Client Credentials"

For this flow - we need to post the client api and secret to a generate token endpoint - which gives us the token that needs to be passed each time.  Since Data Studio doesn't seem to support this config - It doesn't look like i can make it work.  Here is documentation that shows a typical Oauth2 grant credentials flow : https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/client-credentials

I will suggest it as a feature request if its not possible.

Comment: It seems the Apps Script OAuth2 library does support `"grant_type":"client_credentials"`: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/commit/814d2393bc7af5567cafabf74e7c6cf332daf06f. If you still need help with this, it might be best to follow up with the Apps Script DevRel team through that GitHub repo.

Comment: Hi - yes I saw that however its the dataStudio api seem to require a #baseurl when you select Oauth2.  --see screen: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/auth … under oAuth2. If you add me on twitter or such - I can share my code so you can see for yourself.  I am planning on open sourcing it anyway.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but did anyone come up with a solution? Same exact situation-- I need to create a connector using OAuth2, and I can get the token in Postman, but don't have a base auth URL, so haven't been able to figure out how to make it work in a Google Data Studio connector.